# Delete records by trigger in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, triggers, delete-record

My case:

I have to tables A and B. Both of them have columns named 'ID'.

I want to remove records from table B, after insert record to table A. For example, when I insert to table A record with ID = 50, I want to remove from table B all records when ID = 50.

I wanted to use 'After Insert' trigger, but there is no option 'Delete Record' in other table.

It's worth adding that in my case I can't use sql query to delete records.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"I can't use sql query to delete records"* Why not?

Comment: I can't, because (i will continue my example), there id a case, when I can insert back the row with ID=50 to table B, but with changed other information. So removing row with ID=50 id proper only in moment of inserting data to table A.